# How to set null value (by default) to drop-down list in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

In my model class for view, I have an enum type property `SubjectType`:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
public SubjectType SubjectType { get; set; }
```

I would like to create drop-down list for this property. But by default I would like it to be set to **null** so that user has to choose something, and the validation message will be shown if he would try to submit form without choosing any option.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

I was trying to change `SubjectType` property to nullable, and setting the default value to **null**, but the validation still passed on this field (somehow) and the form was submitted to the server. By default the value of this field was set to the first value from enum definition. No JavaScript allowed, I'd like to keep everything in code-behind. I will be grateful for any advice.

so far i render it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SubjectType", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(SubjectType)))
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubjectType)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubjectType)
```

Comment: How are you rendering the dropdown ? Your view code ? How are you passing the items(what are those) to build the dropdown ?

Comment: edited the post; the EnumHelper is in System.Web.Mvc assembly, under System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace

Comment: is rendering the list using foreach an option for u ?

Comment: It does not work. The null vlaue is posted and validaiton no fired.

Comment: as i mentioned I'd like to have client side validation for this field

Comment: I have followed your steps exactly. Your solution is incorrect

Comment: look I'm not an idiot and your solution doesnt work, deal with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118428/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dupa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to solve problem doing this:
Change submit button to button with onclick action, then validate it in javascript and if form and this enum field is valid submit the form using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think the problem was three fold. first your attribute is named SubjectType but your dropdown is named Type so it cannot be bound to SubjectType.

second, Apparently you have to use @HTML.dropdownlistfor(). I did a viewsource with my two different versions dropdown and dropdownlistfor and dropdownlistfor is the only one that adds the validation classes (see below)

third, we needed to add the option label parameter "Select a Type" as a default value.  I'm sure it'll work for you now.

In Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Error!")]
public string SubjectType{ get; set; }
```

In Html:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubjectType, new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SubjectType))), "Select a Type", new { @class = "pretty" } )
```

now I see you have a helper that furnishes an enumerable I think that will be just fine if you replace my second param with that.

Dropdownlist vs DropdownlistFor Rendering of Select Element:

DropdownList:

```
<select name="SubjectType" class="pretty" id="SubjectType">...</select>
```

DropdownListFor:

```
<select name="SubjectType" class="pretty" id="SubjectType" data-val-required="Error!" data-val="true">...</select>
```

As you can see data-val-required and data-val classes are missing when doing a simple dropdown thus not turning on validation FOR that attribute.  Sorry for all the pain of getting here. Don't forget to mark me right if it works.

Comment: it's not raising validation message and the form submists with SubjectType property value as first of values in enum definition; it only displays additional option "Select a type" which is set as default

Comment: maybe something's wrong with my required attribute? should it be replaced with something like "required not empty string"?

nah it does not make sense, the type of property in podel is enum not string

Comment: let me check something over here

Comment: Do you have all the scripts loaded for unobtrusive validation?

Comment: i checked it in browser, definitely included

Comment: is validation working for your other items on your page?

Comment: I noticed that your attribute is called SubjectType you named the dropdown "Type". This would inhibit the binding because binding is based on the name attribute of your elements.

Comment: it's still not working; null value is posted to server

Comment: I'm sorry I had a working solution then pared it down to the essentials.  and tested but my test must have been running on cached code cause this morning my test failed.  The solution is you need dropdownlistfor that is what worked for me.

Comment: I've edited the solution it is tested and working.  I cant help if it doesn't work now.  Good luck.